# Azure Dev-Ops Query based suite adds items 3 times

Tags: testing, azure-devops, test-plan

I am creating Test Plans using Query Based Suites and am getting multiple items.

1. Create a Query based suite with very simple rules -> Run Query
2. Let's say 6 items are returned. I select all 6 and click "Create Suite"
3. The Suite that is created has 18 items (each of the 6 items is copied 3 times)

Any ideas how I can get this to stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No no no, the issue is it adds it to a different configurations:

[image]

So in order to see 1 test instead of 3 you need to click right mouse button on the configuration and un-assign all configs that you don't need. 
[image]

Where to adjust default settings I don't know :(

Comment: OMG - Thank you so much! That was exactly it. I thought I was losing my mind!!!! Much appreciated :-)